# How can I code to close an open workbook using its directory path instead of its name using vba in excel?

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

So I've written a script that opens a certain workbook using its directory pathway (through text from a userform textbox) and I want to be able to close it at the end of the script.
My script currently opens a workbook using the file directory and copies something from that workbook and pastes it into the current workbook. The only thing I want to add is that workbook closing at the end of the sub.

```
Sub A()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    strFirstFile = Userform1.Command.Text
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
    With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Range("A1").Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
    End With
    Set wbk = ThisWorkbook
    wbk.Sheets("dog").Range("A1").Insert

End Sub
```

Bear with me I'm a super newbie.

Comment: Don't use the same variable, `wbk`, for both workbooks. Then you can close `wbk`, as in armsthb's answer.

Comment: thanks that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close the Workbook:

```
wbk.Close
```

If you want to save the workbook beforehand, do:

```
wbk.Save
wbk.Close
```